# CPU usage by Adobe Dreamweaver on a HP probook G1 450 - i5 Quad Core

Tags: windows-7, multi-core, dreamweaver

Is CPU usage of 40% - 50% normal when running Adobe Dreamweaver CS6, or is there an underlying problem? My laptop is a HP ProBook G1 450, i5 Quad Core, and has 8GB RAM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a common problem with cs6, prior to the v12.1 patch:

> If you have installed Dreamweaver CCM update (12.1), you should no
>   longer face this issue. If you have 12.1 update installed and are
>   still facing this problem, let us know. For users that are not on the
>   cloud, Adobe is working towards a release that addresses this issue.
>
> --Preran, Adobe Staff Member, 2013

[Adobe forums](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1001113?start=0&tstart=0)